# Police searched the house [preposition/ prepositional phrase] the murder case. Fill the blank

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

If police carry out some investigative activities (for example, interrogation) as part of an investigation of some particular case, how can denote the connection between the former and the latter (with what preposition or phrase)? I already used 'as part of' but I wonder if I can do it otherwise, for example with a single preposition. For instance,

> Police conducted a search in the suspect's apartment [in/on/for/ in connection with...] the murder case.

Answer (score 1):

Police conducted a search in the suspect's apartment **in connection with** the murder case.

[In connection with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20connection%20with)

Comment: I know that it fits, actually. But could it be expressed with a single preposition?